# WTForms field defaults suddenly don't work

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have the following code:

```
class ReconForm(Form):
    compressedFilePath = StringField('Compressed File Path', [validators.Required()] )
```

and I instantiate it like this:

```
form = ReconForm()
form.compressedFilePath.default = 'hey'
```

It does nothing. It used to set the default value to hey but then it stopped and I have no idea why.

If I print form.compressedFilePath.default then it prints the correct value. If I set a default in the field constructor the template renders the correct value. Otherwise it just does nothing and it's driving me crazy.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you recently installed a newer version of WTForms?

Comment: I don't think so. I changed it to .data instead of .default for a while and then changed it back and it started working again. Could it be to do with caching or something?

Comment: I've never set the default value that way, so I wasn't aware that it ever worked. Code doesn't usually stop working on its own, though. That's why my initial thought was that perhaps you upgraded to a newer version of WTForms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the two ways I know to set a default value for a field using WTForms.

1. To set the value to be the default for all instances of a form, declare the value in the field's definition.

   ```
   class ReconForm(Form):
       compressedFilePath = StringField(
           'Compressed File Path', [validators.Required()], default='hi')

   form = ReconForm()
   ```

   To verify:

   ```
   assert 'value="hi"' in str(form.compressedFilePath)
   ```
2. To set the value to be the default for just a specific instance of the form, specify the value at instantiation.

   ```
   class ReconForm(Form):
       compressedFilePath = StringField(
           'Compressed File Path', [validators.Required()])

   form = ReconForm(compressedFilePath='hi')
   ```

   To verify:

   ```
   assert 'value="hi"' in str(form.compressedFilePath)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Really old question but there is an easier way - just call `process()` on your form after setting the default value.